# Xamarin Forms DisplayActionSheet Outside Touch Error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Displayactionsheet for confirmation before deleting item from listview.

```
var action = await DisplayActionSheet("Delete Item !", "Yes", "No", "Press YES to delete item");
        Debug.Write(action);
        if (action.Equals("Yes"))
        {
            var image = sender as ImageButton;
            var item = image?.BindingContext as Product_Value2;
            var vm = BindingContext as ItempageVM;
            vm?.Delete.Execute(item);

        }
        else if (action.Equals("No"))
        {

        }
```

If i choose yes or no, i am getting the desired result.when i press outside this box, shows this error:

```
Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
Unhandled Exception:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

How to handle this exception?

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint at `Debug.Write(action);` and seeing what `action` is?

Comment: shows this:  [0:]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you press outside, action is null, so you can check for null and do whatever you desire

```
        var action = await DisplayActionSheet("Delete Item !", "Yes", "No", "Press YES to delete item");

        if(action == null)
        {
           //Your logic here
        }
        else if (action.Equals("Yes"))
        {
            var image = sender as ImageButton;
            var item = image?.BindingContext as Product_Value2;
            var vm = BindingContext as ItempageVM;
            vm?.Delete.Execute(item);

        }
        else if (action.Equals("No"))
        {

        }
```